# Queries failed to run

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, temp-tables

I am working on a Microsoft Access database to keep track of some issues we are having. 
When I run my SQl statement I get an "operation must use an updateable query" error. From my understanding this is because of Jet 4.0.

Here is my current query (it is a valid statement):

```
UPDATE 2HEADPERDAYPAY
SET 2HEADPERDAYPAY.TOTALPAY = (SELECT Sum(TOTALPAY) AS Expr1 FROM 2HEADPERDAYFIGURE WHERE ((([2HEADPERDAYFIGURE].VENDOR)=[2HEADPERDAYFIGURE].[VENDOR])))
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [2HEADPERDAYFIGURE] WHERE Vendor=[2HEADPERDAYPAY].Vendor);
```

I need to make this work in my Access database and I do not know how.

Comment: I did... When I run a SQl statement i get an operation must use an update able query

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the behavior is intentional. So, scroll down to the Resolution header and read up:

(https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/175168)

Good luck.

Comment: thanks, i have seen this, i am asking how should i rewrite my sql statement to make it work, not simple permission changes. pleas provide helpful answers